# How to create dropdown list and automatically update values of a specific cell in google sheet using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google sheet and automation using appscript, and I would appreciate your help to my query. How can I create a dropdown list of months in column A, and automatically update the value of "P8" with the last day of month in selected in column A, and set a value of "1.250" to column L & M. I have attached here the screenshot of my google workbook, for reference:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UWjl.jpg)

And currently, I have this code in appscript:

> 

```
 var today = new Date();
 var year = today.getFullYear();

 var actualSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
 var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(actualSheetName); 

 Logger.log(actualSheetName);

 var leavePeriod = sheetName.getRange("P8"); 
 leavePeriod.setValue(year);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

First function sets up columnA with a month drop down

```
function colAToMonthsDropDown() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const val = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList([...new Array(12).keys()].map(k => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), k, 15), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMMM"))).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
  const colA = sh.getRange("A2:A" + sh.getLastRow()).clearContent().clearDataValidations().setDataValidation(val);
}
```

This is an onEdit(e) function which works when editing columnA below row 1 and leaves a value in column A

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    let idx = [...new Array(12).keys()].map(k => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), k, 15), e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MMMM")).indexOf(e.value);
    e.source.toast(`Gate1 e.value: ${e.value} idx: ${idx}`);
    if(~idx) {
      let ld = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),idx + 1,0),e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"d");
      e.source.toast(`Gate2 ld: ${ld}`)
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,16).setValue(ld).setNumberFormat("0.###############");
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,13).setValue(1.250).setNumberFormat("#.000");
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,14).setValue(1.250).setNumberFormat("#.000");
    }
  }
}
```

This version copies last date of the month to P8

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    let idx = [...new Array(12).keys()].map(k => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), k, 15), e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MMMM")).indexOf(e.value);
    e.source.toast(`Gate1 e.value: ${e.value} idx: ${idx}`);
    if(~idx) {
      let ld = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),idx + 1,0),e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"d");
      e.source.toast(`Gate2 ld: ${ld}`)
      sh.getRange("P8").setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),idx + 1,0),e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"MMMM dd, yyyy"))
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,13).setValue(1.250).setNumberFormat("#.000");
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,14).setValue(1.250).setNumberFormat("#.000");
    }
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: wow. this helps! thank you. 